# A question about union of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question pertains to [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319215/if-the-sum-of-the-probabilities-of-events-is-equal-to-the-probability-of-their-u?newreg=638e8aeff9e74ff786f2255d6019dd66)

if $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(E_{i})$, then

$P(E_{i}\cap E_{j})=0$ for $i\neq j$.

How do I prove this?.

What I have tried:-

$P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i})=\lim_{m\to\infty}P(\cup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i})$ (From continuity of Probability).

$P(\cup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i})=P(E_{1})+P(E_{2}/E_{1})+P(E_{3}/E_{2}\cap E_{3})+....$

Now I can write $P(A/B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B).$

Now using this I get $P(\cup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i})\geq \sum_{i=1}^{m}P(E_{i})-\sum_{i<j}P(E_{i}\cap E_{j})$.

However this inequality does not yield anything. If the sign of the inequality was opposite then I could have concluded what I want . Can anyone help me prove this?.

Comment: I think the statement to be proven is given by $P(E_i \cap E_j)=0$

Comment: Yeah sorry . I miswrote cup instead of cap

Comment: @Surb How?. I know that if they are probability of intersection of all pairs is 0 then the probability of union is equal to the sum of probabilities. But how to show the converse. Can you please help me out?.

Comment: Try induction on finite prefixes. Can you show it for a finite collection $E_1,\ldots,E_n$, if you know it is true for all collections of $n-1$ sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\cup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i})\\=P(\cup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i}\backslash E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{i-1})\\=\sum_{i=1}^{m}P(E_{i}\backslash E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{i-1}) \\\le \sum_{i=1}^{m}P(E_{i})$

since $P(E_{i}\backslash E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{i-1}) \le P(E_{i})$

and for equality you need $P(E_{i}\backslash E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{i-1}) = P(E_{i})$ for all $i$,

which implies $P(E_{i}\cap E_j)=0$ for all $i \not=j$